# Unable to update the input file list

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add multiple images by using Laravel and it works fine by using the following command.

```
<input type="file" id="images" name="images[]" onchange="preview_image();" multiple accept="image/*"><br/>
<div id="image_preview"></div>

<script>

function preview_image() 
{
 var total_file=document.getElementById("images").files.length;
 for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
 {
  $('#image_preview').append("<img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'>");
 }
}

</script>
```

but when i try to add more images, input file list clear and add the new list. I want to know how to keep the old files when i add new files.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `preview_image()` have argument `event`.

Comment: it shows preview properly. but i want to add more files to the file list

Comment: i can even upload the files to the database. But i dont know how to add new files to the existing list before uploading to the database

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/adminpanel/dvgallery', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'method' => 'Post', 'files'=>true)) !!}
         
 Upload Images: <input type="file" id="images" name="images[]" onchange="preview_image();" multiple accept="image/*"><br/>


  <div id="image_preview"></div>

Comment: @Sawad if you want to add mulltiple files just hold down `ctrl` while selecting the files.

Comment: @Sawad just know that the preview will not represent what is being uploaded, since the input list is overwritten each time files are selected.

Comment: @Sawad i don't think you can add more files each time, you would have to do it yourself using an array of file names.

Comment: how to add more files in to the existing list?

Comment: @Sawad the FileList object in the input is readonly, meaning that you cannot change it. I would advise you to use a javascript library like http://www.dropzonejs.com/.